# Adding element to array forces view update

Tags: swiftui

I'm running in the following problem: I have a list with some realm objects that are displayed. Each element has a checkbox. When the element I've selected the checkbox is activated and the object should be stored in an array. The problem is that when I add this selected object to my array it seems that the complete view will be updated and the object is not selected anymore.

The ViewModel for the main view looks like this:

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var entries: Results<DictionaryEntry>? // realm objects 
    @Published var selectedEntries = [DictionaryEntry]() 
    ...
}
```

The ViewModel for each entry is:

```
class ElementViewModel: ObservableObject { 
    @Published var checked = false 
    @Published var element: DictionaryEntry 
    ....
 }
```

Main view:

```
...
@EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

ScrollView {
    ForEach(mainViewModel.entries) { entry in 
        DictionaryEntry(elementViewModel: ElementViewModel(entry: entry)) 
        ...
    }
    
    Text("\(mainViewModel.selectedEntries.count)" entries are selected)
 }
```

View for `DicitionaryEntry`

```
@ObservedObject var elementViewModel: ElementViewModel 
@EnvironmentObject var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
...
Text(elementViewModel.element.title)
Button(action: {
    if !elemetViewModel.checked {
        elementViewModel.checked = true 
        mainViewModel.selectedEntries.append(elementViewModel.element) // <--- problem line!
        // draw checkbox
    } else { 
        elementViewModel.checked = false 
        // remove element from mainViewModel.selectedEntries
        // draw checkbox
```

Since I'm using the mainViewModel as an EnvironmentObject:

```
struct myApp: App {
    @StateObject var mainViewModel = MainViewModel() 

    var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        TabBarView()
            .environmentObject(mainViewModel)
    }
 }
```

I know that I can change `@Published var selectedEntries = [DictionaryEntry]()`to `var selectedEntries = [DictionaryEntry]()`. But then the text with "XY entries are selected" won't be automatically updated.

Comment: Published updates view via observed object by design. As I see you've got into conflict of interests, which should be solved at logic level, not UI (eg. make elementViewModel.checked persistent)

Comment: Do you mean with "persistent" to save that attribute in a database? Or is there another way?

Comment: @Asperi would be glad if you could explain your answer a little bit more. I've tried to save that property in a database but it's a little bit inefficient and slow. Is there no opportunity to solve this without database interactions?